# Не работает на веб-сервере, но на локальном все окей

Tags: php

При выгрузке на рабочий сервер появилась проблема, что ругается на эту строку и ей подобные:

```
 /** Директория для хранения файлов */
        'UPLOAD_DIR' => __DIR__ .'/../../../data/upload/',
```

Сама ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in

То есть это ключ-элемент массива, но почему он ругается на точку? Как исправить?

Comment: Ну если работает там, а не работает тут или наоборот, возможно дело в версии PHP. Вот тут обсуждается данная проблема - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759905/concatenating-dir-constant-with-a-string-as-an-array-value-which-is-a-class

Comment: Действительно, разница в 5.4 и 5.6. Спасибо вам!